# send email with python - unauthorized sender address

Tags: python, email, smtp

I tried sending an email with python using the email-provider "web.de". 
I activated email protocols in the settings of the email service provider. 
The following error message occurs:

```
(554, b'Transaction failed\nUnauthorized sender address.')
```

It should be possible to do it because my email programs can send emails.

```
import smtplib, ssl

smtp_server = "smtp.web.de"
port = 587  # For starttls
sender_email = "someemail@web.de"
password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
receiver_email = "another@web.de"
message = "Subject: Hi there\n\nThis message is sent from Python."

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Try to log in to server and send email
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)

except Exception as e:
    # Print any error messages to stdout
    print(e)
finally:
    server.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would advise you to use sendinblue, it is awesome and it is free to some extent.

Coming to your question, I don't think you should be asking for the senders password, since they might not give it to you. Next I think the senders email should have the email that you have registered with your email provider, not the email a person provides. The receiver email is good to go I guess. But I think this part has some problems:

```
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

I think you forgot to write the subject of the email, which is likely triggering the error. I have never sent emails with python, but I have used python web framework django, and it shows error if the subject of the email is not provided.

Try this:

```
try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP(smtp_server,port)
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.starttls(context=context) # Secure the connection
    server.ehlo() # Can be omitted
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail("This is the subject", sender_email, receiver_email, message)
```

also i think the receiver email should be a list, not just a string, because the number of recipients can change. Put it in a list like this even if you don't want to send it to a lot of people.

```
receiver_email = ["another@web.de"]
```

You can new recipients by putting a comma and writing the second recipient in quotes.

Comment: When I include a forth argument in the sendmail function like you said, it gives me the following error message: (500, b'Syntax error, command unrecognized', 'this is the subject'). This also happens when I use a string variable instead of just putting in a string.